# Are the Statistics of SCR Leakage Current Stationary?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

When I measure the leakage current of an active device, in this case an SCR, is that leakage current likely to stay roughly constant throughout the life of the device?

Why this is a physics question: The answer, it seems to me, relies on solid state physics knowledge that is more specialized than most EE's have. While I'm absolutely open to insights gained by working in the semiconductor industry, I am reaching out to a community with a lot of theoretical knowledge on this subject simply because I've never heard of anyone trying to answer this question empirically. No, I'm not suggesting that engineers are empirical and physicists are theoretical. That would be horribly inaccurate. I am asking the physics community specifically because you have the tools to answer a question that most engineers are ill equipped for, myself included.

Comment: No, there are any number of ways for the characteristics of solid state devices to drift with time. These include annealing, radiation effects, junction spiking, hot carrier degradation, dopant diffusion, overvoltages, ...

Comment: @JonCuster can you move this to an answer? I would like to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reliability of electronic devices has long been a concern for both the military and industry.

In 1961, the US Department of Defense released the first version of MIL-HDBK-217 Reliability Prediction of Electronic Equipment, with version F, notice 2 being released in 1991. This is easy to find out on the internet, and is freely downloadable. This handbook presents equations, empirically determined, for failure rates of a wide range of devices and integrated circuits. No attempt at attributing failures to specific mechanisms is made.

In 1968, MIL-STD-883 Test Method Standard Microcircuits was released, with the latest being version L in 2019. This provides 108 standard test methods that cover a wide range of environmental, mechanical, and electrical tests that could be performed on devices to assess conformance to requirements. From the various tests one can infer several possible device characteristic degradation issues:

- 1002 Immersion - water tends to cause things like corrosion, etc.
- 1010 Temperature cycling - varying mechanical stresses
- 1011 Thermal shock - rapid temperature changes
- 1017 Neutron irradiation - radiation effects
- 1020 Dose rate induced latchup - radiation effects
- 1031 Thin film corrosion test - increased resistivity of wires
- 2002 Mechanical shock - break something
- 2005 Vibration fatigue - break something eventually
- 2015 Resistance to solvents
- 2019 Die shear strength
- 2021 Glassivation layer integrity (protects die from environment)
- 3015 Electrostatic discharge sensitivity
- 3020/3021 Output leakage current

Still, while developing these tests was driven by observed failures, the failure mechanisms are not necessarily directly indicated by them. Further, these are test standards for production and acceptance of devices, not a way of determining actual physical failure mechanisms.

So, on to [Microelectronics Reliability: Physics-of-Failure Based Modeling and Lifetime Evaluation](https://nepp.nasa.gov/files/16365/08_102_4_%20JPL_White.pdf), a joint publication from JPL (Pasadena) and the University of Maryland which has long had a microelectronics reliability center. In that 219 page report, they claim that the major 'wearout' mechanisms are electromigration, gate-oxide breakdown (time-dependent dielectric breakdown), and hot carrier effects. They do not consider radiation effects, mechanical shock, thermal shock, etc., as wearout mechanisms. They mean bad things that can happen while the chip sits there nicely and just works as intended in a benign environment.

However, any of the wearout or other events can lead to shifts in device characteristics. Neutron irradiation will alter transistor gain. X-ray irradiation will change MOSFET threshold voltages. Thermal shock may start a bond pad lifting, introducing a higher resistance leading to more heat generated there, which drives bad things. Operation above temperature limits may allow dopant diffusion in junctions, changing device characteristics, as well as letting external impurities diffuse in through the package, causing shifts (sodium is particularly bad for CMOS).

So, (1) there has been a great deal of effort over the years to quantify reliability, establish standard tests to conform to to enhance measured reliability, and understand what the exact mechanisms for failure (or device drift) are so they can be mitigated. For example, decades of research has looked at electromigration issues. And, (2) as the industry keeps moving to smaller dimensions and new materials, this opens up potential new failure mechanisms.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much!!!